# Please help. Function not printing

Tags: c, function

Help, my function yearToVote is not printing out any statements.  The function is supposed to calculate how many elections someone would be able to vote based on their birthday, not sure why the function is not printing anything based on the if statements.  Run the program if you need to see what I am trying to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

//Prototype
double calc_age(const unsigned int m, const unsigned int d, const unsigned int y);
void yearToVote(int daysAge, int birthDay, int birthMonth);
void ageNextElection(AgeinDays);

int main()
{
    int month, day, year, AgeinDays;



    printf("Enter birthday (mm): ");
    scanf("%d", &month);
    printf("Enter birthday (dd): ");
    scanf("%d", &day);
    printf("Enter birthday (yyyy): ");
    scanf("%d", &year);
//Call
    AgeinDays = calc_age(month, day, year);
    printf("%d \n", AgeinDays -1);

    ageNextElection(AgeinDays);

    yearToVote(AgeinDays, day, month);

}

//First Function: Calculates Age in Days
double calc_age(const unsigned int m1, const unsigned int d1, const unsigned int y1) {  //unsigned - can't be negative.  const- can't be cahnged


    struct tm t = {0};
    time_t t_of_day;

    t.tm_year = y1 - 1900;
    t.tm_mon = m1 -1;
    t.tm_mday = d1;
    t.tm_isdst = -1;
    t_of_day = mktime(&t);

    time_t now;
    time(&now);

    return  round((difftime(now,t_of_day)/(60.0*60.0*24.0)));
}

//Second Function: How many times and years voted
void yearToVote(int daysAge, int Bday, int Bmonth)
{
int A, B, m[11] = {0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 374}, monthsDay;

A = daysAge/365;

if (Bmonth == 1){
    monthsDay = m[0];

}
if (Bmonth == 2){
    monthsDay = m[1];

}
if (Bmonth == 3){
    monthsDay = m[2];

}
if (Bmonth == 4){
    monthsDay = m[3];

}
if (Bmonth == 5){
    monthsDay = m[4];

}
if (Bmonth == 6){
    monthsDay = m[5];

}
if (Bmonth == 7){
    monthsDay = m[6];

}
if (Bmonth == 8){
    monthsDay = m[7];

}
if (Bmonth == 9){
    monthsDay = m[8];

}
if (Bmonth == 10){
    monthsDay = m[9];

}
if (Bmonth == 11){
    monthsDay = m[10];

}
if (Bmonth == 12){
    monthsDay = m[11];

}

B = Bday + monthsDay;


if (A >= 18){
    if (daysAge <= 1986 && daysAge >= 1980 && B <= 307) {
            printf ("You could have voted in the last 4 elections and this election.\n");
    } else if (daysAge <= 1990 && daysAge > 1986 && B <= 307) {
            printf ("You could have voted in the last 3 elections and this election.\n");
    } else if (daysAge <= 1994 && daysAge > 1990 && B <= 307) {
            printf ("You could have voted in the last 2 elections and this election.\n");
    } else if (daysAge <= 1998 && daysAge > 1994 && B <= 307) {
            printf ("You could have voted in the last election and this election.\n");
    } else if (daysAge <= 2002 && daysAge > 1998 && B <= 307) {
            printf ("You can vote in this election.\n");
    } else if (daysAge >= 2002 && B > 307) {
            printf("You are not eligible to vote.\n");
}

}

}

//Third Function: Age in Eligibility of next election
void ageNextElection(int AgeinDays){
    int AgeinNext;
    AgeinDays = AgeinDays + 1460;

    AgeinNext = AgeinDays / 365;

    printf("Your age in the next election is: %d \n", AgeinNext);

    if(AgeinNext >= 18){
        printf("You are eligible to vote next election! \n");
    }
    else{
        printf("You will not be eligible to vote \n");
    }

}
```

Comment: "not sure why the function is not printing". Perfect time to use a debugger. Step through the code line by line in a debugger and examine the variable values as it runs. After that if you still need help, please provide the exact test input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: Why do you need all those `if` statements? Just use `monthsDay = m[Bmonth-1]`

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Got it working, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On my computer your code seems OK:

```
Enter birthday (mm): 01
Enter birthday (dd): 01
Enter birthday (yyyy): 2000
7611
Your age in the next election is: 24
You are eligible to vote next election!
```

Of course, there are some things to fix:

```
src/main.c:132:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
  132 | void ageNextElection(AgeinDays);
      | ^~~~
src/main.c: In function 'yearToVote':
src/main.c:178:70: warning: excess elements in array initializer
  178 | int A, B, m[11] = {0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 374}, monthsDay;
      |                                                                      ^~~
src/main.c:178:70: note: (near initialization for 'm')
```